# Cheating online test javascript timer

Tags: javascript, timer

First of all, I have no intention of cheating, I'm just one of these people who tend to see flaws everywhere.

These days before the job interview you may be required to do online test, most of them have javascript timers (countdown), so you don't have enough time to google the answers.

But the way I see it (correct me if I'm wrong), timer is just a decreasing variable that once reaches 0 (say) stops the test. I seems that in many cases it is possible to look the source code, find the name of the variable and force-increase it using the console, so you have all time in the world.

I'm interested is it always possible to manipulate such "timer" variable using console, or there are ways to prevent it?

Comment: If the test isn't ridiculous, the real timer is server side

Comment: Yes, it's quite easy to manipulate a JavaScript variable from console / developper tool

Comment: I think it would be easier just to answer the questions in the required time instead of "cheating"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the the test is a pure web page probably you can not manipulate it, because the timer or some kind of limit checker should be on server side. Means you can change the time in your browser maybe, but if the test is correctly implemented, after the time is over, you can not send your answers in anymore.